# Mobile Chat application on Google App Engine and Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I am creating a chat application with Node.js's Socket.IO and there are a couple of things I need clarification on.

I am implementing offline messaging in my app meaning that when a user opens the app he will receive all the messages he missed when they were online.

This is my approach:

1. The client opens the app and is subscribed or joins a room.
2. The client sends a message to Socket.IO.
3. Socket.IO inserts the message in some kind of database/datastore.
4. When the client tries to retrieve the messages it is pulled from the database/datastore and saved on the user's phone, then it is deleted from the database.

Is this a correct approach?

I was looking online and some people suggested using task/message queues like Google App Engines Task Queue, but I am not sure how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds OK, but I wouldn't delete messages from a DB, at least not immediately after the client receives them.

From your question it seems that you're not currently saving the messages to a database.
This approach has some drawbacks; for example, the user can't view their chat history on a device that was not connected when some of the messages were sent.

There are 2 ways I can think of to do it in a more elegant manner:

1. Save all messages to DB. on websocket connection and reconnections, fetch all messages newer than your latest message (This approach assumes no edit functionality in your chat, as edits will not be fetched this way). The latter can be implemented using either `HTTP` or `WebSockets`.
2. If you don't want to store the messages in your server, then you should implement some sort of persistent cache in the device used to send the messages. This is very similar to your original solution, except that instead of storing the messages in a database, you're storing them on the user's device. this does require some logic to detect when messages are received, and when the recipient reconnects, in order to trigger sending the missing messages.

The first approach is much better for the general use case in my opinion, but it depends on your use case.

Comment: Why would it not be good to delete messages from my database? @nadavvadan

Comment: Because then you're not saving the user's chat history. This depends on your use case, but I would imagine you'd want to save the chat's history in a DB, so that the information can be accessed by other devices / from the same device after deletion of data by the user. Again, not suitable for all applications, so I'm addressing what strikes me as the most common use case.

Comment: And can message queues replace database in this context. For example can I use RabbitMQ instead of storing the messages in a database?

Comment: I get what you mean about chat history it is all very specific for context of the app. Thanks for the reply glad Im on the right track

Comment: using RabbitMQ/ZeroMQ/Redis/other messaging queues, is possible. but is it necessary for your application? I don't think so. it might be fun to experiment with, but unless you're expecting a lot of traffic, `websockets` should suffice and are easier to configure, in addition to being supported in web browsers (so you could, in theory, build a web application for your app as well). I'd probably choose WebSockets and a DB.